# How to control one motor with two float switches

Tags: power-supply, switches, induction-motor, level, contactor

I have 2 tanks , one is under another and hopes to pump from under tank to upper one using a 0.5 Hp single phase motor.By connecting float switches for both tank,can I control the motor to turn on when the water level of lower tank is high and switches off when the water level of upper tank is high ( Upper tank has lower capacity than Lower ) and vise versa

Comment: Certainly, yes.

Comment: I have question with the circuit, each float switch has 3 wires, what are the wires i need to use

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to add links to the datasheet for the switches. We can't guess.

Comment: https://www.wiltec.de/float-switch-pump-level-controller-cable-5m.html

Comment: You need to edit your question to add links to the datasheet for the switches. Don't hide them in the comments.

Comment: I suspect that you want to control one motor with two switches, rather than have the motor control the switches, as the title says.

Comment: Do you want to keep the upper tank filled (ie, pump where upper tank not full AND lower tank not empty) or to only start pumping when the lower tank is full?

Answer (score 2):

According to the datasheet the sensor and under the assumption that it works like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tA76sm_jJTk it can be used directly without the need of any additional circuit:

[image]

The parts are taken from the datasheet chart 2 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using a relay, wired up as a latch. You have the high-limit switch as SPDT type which can serve as a cut-off.

Here's how it works:

- The lower tank-high switch energizes the coil.
- Relay self-energizes through one set of contacts, which latches it.
- The upper tank-high switch turns off the relay, latch opens.

The connection looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkIeor.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>